# Does Lync 2013 support multiple instances?

Tags: vpn, multiple-instances, lync

I want to use Lync within my organization's network, and also I'm connected to a VPN, and I'd like to have another instance of Lync for handling the uers of the other network.

My colleagues currently use Lync 2010 from a locally installed virtual machine to achieve this double instance.

So can this be done? and if so, could I get some hints on how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

If you're running Windows 8, you can install the desktop client and the Windows Store app for different accounts simultaneously.

You could also use a web interface (OWA) provided by Microsoft Office 365 or previous similar solutions.

You could also try to install Lync 2010 and Lync 2013 on the same system and use them simultaneously to achieve this though.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to download the [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/download/) and configure it with your account settings.

Also you can install a Windows virtual machine with Lync on it and use it as second one.

Comment: Did that. Very important, for anyone else trying this: It worked with Pidgin **2.10.2**, but it didn't work with the newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Windows 8/10**, you can try to install the **Lync** app from the **Windows store** which can act as second instance.

I have 'Skype for Business' as part Office 2013 pack and 'Lync' from windows store. Check image below-

[Skype for business and Lync in same machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVMxk.png)